# Change icon of moving marker of Google Map

Tags: icons, maps

I have a code which moves between lattitude and longitude on google map. I want to change the icon of the marker and also align the map in between of start points of lattitude, longitude and end points of lattitude, longitude. Please can you guys help me? Thanks in advance

Here's my code:

```
<script>
var markers = [];
function initialize() {

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $mapdata->deplat?>,<?php echo $mapdata->deplng;?>),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var startPos = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $mapdata->deplat?>,<?php echo $mapdata->deplng;?>);
var endPos = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $mapdata->arrlat?>,<?php echo $mapdata->arrlng;?>);


// generate fake points for route
var pointsNo = 80;
var latDelta = (endPos.lat() - startPos.lat()) / pointsNo;
var lngDelta = (endPos.lng() - startPos.lng()) / pointsNo;
var positions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < pointsNo; i++) {
    var curLat = startPos.lat() + i * latDelta;
    var curLng = startPos.lng() + i * lngDelta;
    positions.push(new google.maps.LatLng(curLat, curLng));


    var curMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(curLat, curLng),
        visible: false
    });
    markers.push(curMarker);
}
}


function displayMarker(markers, index, delay) {    
if (index > 0)
    markers[index - 1].setVisible(false);
else {
    markers[markers.length - 1].setVisible(false);
}

markers[index].setVisible(true);
if (index < markers.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        displayMarker(markers, index + 1, delay);
    }, delay);
} else {
    displayMarker(markers, 0, delay);
}
}


//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
initialize();
//});

$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
var delay = 40;
displayMarker(markers, 0, delay);
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's beautiful and so nice of you to share code, but what exactly is the problem with it? expectations and output or bug reports would help many a genius here.

Comment: Hey, I just want to change the location marker to a flight icon and want to center the map between the start point and end point